# Integer of a Script won't change using another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i am using `GameObject.Find("SAVELOADSYSTEM").GetComponent<LoadManager>().Level = Level;` to get Level integer to the script, the script is simply a finish teleporter.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Finish : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string DebugLog;
    public string SceneName;
    public GameObject Player;
    public int Level;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        var distance = 3;
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.transform.position) < distance && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            GameObject.Find("SAVELOADSYSTEM").GetComponent<LoadManager>().Level = Level;
            Debug.Log(DebugLog);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneName);
        }
    }
}
```

that is the teleporter, simply coming near it and pressing e (interact).
the problem is that i want it to change level integer value at what Level (from this script) is changed to (public int Level;), but the problem is that the save load script that contains Level stage (integer) to save doesn't want to change value with this teleport script.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LoadManager instance;
    public Data data;

    string dataFile = "737472696e67.dotouchit";

    public int Level { get; internal set; }

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Load();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Save();
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + dataFile;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            FileStream file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            Data loaded = (Data)bf.Deserialize(file);
            data = loaded;
            file.Close();


        }
        Debug.Log("Loaded Data");
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + dataFile;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(filePath);
        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();

        Debug.Log("Saved Data");
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Data
    {
        public int level = 0;


        public Data()
        {

            level = 0;
        }

    }


}
```

and that is the save load system script. 
i don't know why it does not want to change level value.

Comment: Don't you get any `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: i don't, i don't get anything. it just works but doesn't change level value.

Comment: Hmm, You don't even get any console output? Even from `Debug.Log(DebugLog);` line?

Comment: i do get that output, but not any error.

Comment: _"i don't know why it does not want to change level value."_ - what value are you expecting? I can't see what you're ever assigning a value to either the `Level` field in the `Finish` class or the `Level` property in the `LoadManager` class. Therefore I would expect them both to be `default(int)` (i.e. 0).

Comment: Level from LoadManager. the one from finish is for assigning Level from LoadManager to the Finish script.

Comment: You are not assigning any value to the Data class you are saving, therefore it will always load the default value.
Regardless try to avoid saving each update.

Comment: 1) Your code assigns a value _to_ `Level` in `LoadManager`. 2) `Level` in `Finish` is 0, so `Level` in `LoadManager` will have 0 assigned to it.

Comment: 0? i don't understand, i have assigned an 1 on the unity editor.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Unity guy. I didn't realise you could assign stuff to the code from somewhere else. Your best option is to set a breakpoint on the assignment line and debug the code.

Comment: i can give you a screenshot if you want to see how it works.

Comment: In general: **Never** use `+ "/"` for System paths! Rather use [`var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,dataFile);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)

Comment: why?
this message was put for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty sure that `Level` value is properly assigned. Well, not *properly*, but let's take the issue later.

The problem is, `level` value in `Data` class is never assigned. You have to initialize it with constructor, like:

```cs
public Data(int level)
{

    this.level = level;
}
```

Or,

```
public void Save()
{
    data.level = level;

    ...
```

Without assigning, your `level` value will always have `0` value. Maybe smart Intelisense would have already noticed you, saying `value Level is assigned, but never used.`

---

About the issue I've mentioned above, WHY are you doing this thing,

```cs
GameObject.Find("SAVELOADSYSTEM").GetComponent<LoadManager>().Level = Level;
```

It seems like you've already declared `LoadManager` with a singleton pattern, so there are no need to do it. If `LoadManager` component is properly attatched to the GameObject, just doing

```cs
LoadManager.instance.Level = Level;
```

would be enough.

Unity `GameObject.Find()` is super heavy function, since it brute-force all gameobject's name in the scene. Calling it once would be fine, but putting this thing in `Update()`? 
Well, doing brute force *60 times* in a second would not so be great situation. That's why using `GameObject.Find()` is recommended, only in `Start()`, `Awake()`, or the initialization of class.

Comment: Then consider changing `GetKey` into `GetKeyDown`. `GetKey` will always return true in the frame then the key has pressed, which would result succesive `Find()` call. And, if there is other way, just *don't* use `GameObject.Find()`. It makes your code less readable, and also may result frame drop, even if called only once.

Comment: yeah, but what about the problem? anyways, the portal would teleport you in 1 frame.

Comment: the constructor will break the save and load system, because Data is important.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I'm not sure why you are saying that modifying the constructor would break the system, but if so then just update the `data`s level value every time you call the save function.

Comment: i can't, because the default data would be level 0, if players complete levels then it would be saved to next levels.